# Image Processing in WPF

Tags: wpf, optimization, image-processing, directx, pixel-shader

I am designing an WPF application which renders data as a 500x500 8-bit indexed image at 10 frames per second using WriteableBitmap.

We would like to add some real-time image processing algorithms to our output, such as 2-D median filtering, gaussian blur or moving average, which are computationaly power hungry.

- Did anyone try to use WPF pixel shaders to do such tasks ?
- Would a platform-specific image processing library be efficient ? (e.g. Intel IPP ?)
- Or would a DirectX based custom renderer be the solution ?

Any tip would be much welcome. At the moment everything is computed within our .NET application and I believe there is room for optimization.

Thank you for your help,

Best Regards,

Romain

Answer (score 1):

If your data is purely for display I would recommend using pixel shaders. The other two options you suggest both require interop with unmanaged code which adds complexity.

Comment: Your opinion about third option is wrong. Take SlimDX + Hlsl or XNA + Hlsl path and you will be within managed code limit. I would suggest SlimDX approach, because in that we can use ComputeShaders, which lets us to do GPGPU programming with DirectX 11.